# Changing all cell border widths in DataGridViews

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a data grid view and I want to make all of the cell borders thicker. Is there a property you can do this with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little custom painting by adding code to the `CellPainting` event handler. For setting the cells border to None, use `CellBorderStyle`:

```
    dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;

// CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
    {
       e.Handled = true;
       using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor))
       {
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);
       }
       using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black))
       {
         p.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
         e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom-1));
       }
       e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes the datagridview have no borders. How would I change the thickness?

Comment: please refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle.aspx